# Angular ng-class dynamic CSS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, coffeescript

There is the following code:

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="o in orders" ng-class="getOrderClass(o)">
```

CoffeeScript:

```
  $scope.getOrderClass = (o) ->
    switch o.orderStatus.title
      when 'New' then 'new-order'
      when 'Completed' then 'completed-order'
```

It code looks good, but there is one problem: After page loading I see 'new-order' class or 'completed-order' class in 'ng-class' attribute, not in 'class'. Where is the mistake? Thanks in advance

Comment: The mistake is that ng-class dynamically adds and removes classes based on an expression that is either true or false.  In your case you're not telling ng-class to add the class, you're simply passing it a static value.  Try adding it to the class attribute or passing back an expression such as  {'new-order': true}.

Answer (score 0):

you can use that structure

```
ng-class="{'new-order' : o.orderStatus.title == 'New', 'completed-order' : o.orderStatus.title == 'Completed'}"
```

Comment: It's very ugly code. I can add more states in the future :) Sorry bro, thanks for attempt

Answer (score 0):

You have used ng-class as an attribute in this case
If you inspect or view source then it would be listed as value of ng-class attribute
If you need the calculated class value in "class" attribute, then use this syntax

If this syntax is used then class attribute will have class name along with expression used to calculate this class

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.getOrderClass = (o) ->
  title = o.orderStatus.title
  {
    'new-order': title == 'New'
    'completed-order': title == 'Completed'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a directive like this

```
app.directive('myClass', [function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      class: '=myClass'
    },
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, controller) {
      elem.addClass(scope.class);
    }
  };
}]);
```

In view:

```
<div my-class="getOrderClass(o)">I have the getOrderClass(o) class</div>
```

I would suggest you somehow cache the result of getOrderClass(o), because when you bind a function call, it will get called on each digest circle. This can cause performance issues in the long run and is usually not a good practice, especially if the function is in an ng-repeat.

It could be something like
`<div ng-repeat="o in orders" my-class="orderClasses[o.id]">I have the getOrderClass(o) class</div>`

Edit: notice that this directive only adds the class once, when the directive is initialized so it won't work like normal two way binding. If you'd like that you also have to add a watcher for scope.class and call elem.addClass again